# How to fix slides in Cycle2 with different widths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle2

I have slides with different slides. When I navigate through my slides using buttons, the slides aren't positioned correctly. Here is my code. I also made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BvgU3/29/) to demonstrate this behavior.

```
<div>
  <button onclick="goto(0)">
    Slide 1
  </button>
  <button onclick="goto(1)">
    Slide 2
  </button>
  <button onclick="goto(2)">
    Slide 3
  </button>
  <button onclick="goto(3)">
    Slide 4
  </button>
</div>
<div style="width:300px">
  <div id="slider"
       data-cycle-fx="carousel"
       data-cycle-timeout="0"
       data-cycle-slides="> div">
    <div style="width:200px;background:red;">
      slide 1
    </div>
    <div style="width:110px;background:blue;">
      slide 2
    </div>
    <div style="width:80px;background:green;">
      slide 3
    </div>
    <div style="width:230px;background:yellow;">
      slide 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slider").cycle();
});

function goto(number){
    $("#slider").cycle('goto', number);
  return false;
}
</script>
```

When first clicking slide 1, then slide 2, slide 3 and finally slide 4, everything works as expected. But when you refresh the page and for example click slide 2 and then slide 1, you see that slide 1 is out of position.

What can I do to fix this?

NOTE: I want to preserve the width of each slide. I don't want to make each slide the same length.

Comment: The slides can't be in the same size?

Comment: No, I don't want to... Otherwise the slide is way to big for some specific data.

Comment: Seems  to me that `cycle` only works with fixed width. :/